# How perform reflection to find all classes that extend a base class in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have a base class of type DataObject which extends other classes. I would like to find all the classes from my main class such that I don't have to import them by hand. How can I achieve this?

Current implementation (import each class that extends DataObject individually):

```
...
   val dataObjects: Array[DataObject] = Array(
     new ExtendedDataObject(),
     new SecondExtendedDataObject(),
     .
     .
     .
     new LastExtendedDataObject(),
   )
   dataObjects.par.foreach(_.doSomething())
...
```

Example of ideal implementation:

```
...
   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      val dataObjects: Array[DataObject] = <method to find all classes extended by DataObject>
      dataObjects.par.foreach(_.doSomething())
   }
...
```

I don't really understand the Scala [Reflection Documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html)

**UPDATE**

Using [org.reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections), how do I turn `dataObjects` into `Array[DataObject]`?

```
...
   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      val reflections = new Reflections("my.package.dataobjects")
      val dataObjects = reflections.getSubTypesOf(classOf[DataObject]).toArray()

   }
...
```

Comment: I don't think that is possible. In what scope would you be looking for these classes? In a certain package? Also dynamic imports aren't possible in Scala, so I don't believe there is any way around importing them one by one. You may have to set up a pre-processor of some sort if this must be done.

Comment: Hi @AndrewAllison, thanks for getting back to me... they are in fact all in subdirectories of a DataObjects directory. Is there a way to scrape that directory for all classes within it and make a list of those classes?

Comment: Consider using https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov thanks for the answer! Do you think you can elaborate on my update?

Comment: Array[DataObject] is an Array of instances of DataObject, Reflections framework gave you classes that extend DataObject, not instances. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @GonzaloGuglielmo you are correct. I am trying to instantiate objects out of the array of classes that I get from the reflection.

Answer (score 1):

According to your answers, what you need is:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val reflections = new Reflections("my.package.dataobjects")
val dataObjects = asScalaSet(reflections.getSubTypesOf(classOf[Base])).map(_.newInstance())
```

That's a mutable set of the instances, if you want to make it inmmutable just:

```
val immutableDataObjects = dataObjects.toSet
```

Comment: Hi @GonzaloGuglielmo, why turn `reflections` into a set, if it already is a set?

Comment: It's a mutable Set, in Scala we usually work with immutable objects, toSet turns the mutable set into an immutable one.